# InternetOpenUrl with self signed certificate

Tags: c++, c, ssl, winapi

The following code is used to download files, but not working if the server has a self signed certificate:

```
DWORD errCode = 0;
HINTERNET intOpenHandle = InternetOpen("Snippet", LOCAL_INTERNET_ACCESS, NULL, 0, 0);
errCode = GetLastError();
if (intOpenHandle != NULL && errCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    HINTERNET urlOpenHandle = InternetOpenUrl(intOpenHandle, url, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    errCode = GetLastError();
    if (urlOpenHandle != NULL && errCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ...
```

Is there a way to modify this to work with self signed certificates, too?

Comment: What is the error code you get? Otherwise try to call InternetSetOption with custom INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/option-flags (like SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_***)

Comment: `ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA` (12045), and tried with `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA` but still the same error...

Comment: Are you calling that before InternetOpenUrl? Try other SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_ flags also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357008/how-to-ignore-certificate-in-httppost-request-in-winapi

Comment: Yes between the `InternetOpen()` and `InternetOpenUrl()` calls, as the latter gave the error 12045. I will try those other `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_*` flags...

Comment: Tried `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA` and `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WEAK_SIGNATURE`, but to no avail...

Comment: Do you have any reproducing code (incl. a server that exhibits the same behavior)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is not possible with `InternetOpenUrl()` and `InternetSetOptions()`: The latter requires an open connection handle, not the session handle the former provides.
Therefore i had to use a bit longer version:

```
DWORD errCode = 0;
HINTERNET intOpenHandle = InternetOpen("Snippet", LOCAL_INTERNET_ACCESS, NULL, 0, 0);
if (intOpenHandle != NULL)
{
     HINTERNET httpRequest = HttpOpenRequest(intConnect, "GET", urlPath, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                             INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
     if (httpRequest != NULL)
     {
         DWORD dwFlags;
         DWORD dwBuffLen = sizeof(dwFlags);
         if (InternetQueryOption(httpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, &dwBuffLen))
         {
             dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WEAK_SIGNATURE |
                        SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE;
             InternetSetOption(httpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, sizeof(dwFlags));
         }
         if (HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
         {
             ...
```

Comment: You could also feel free to [accept your own answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if it does help you.

Comment: Wanted to wait for an upvote, to see if it is helpful to others...

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted this because it's just what I needed, but my flags were slightly different. I'm putting my Delphi version below so the code is readable for anyone else using Delphi or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Delphi solution:

```
var
  Size: DWord;
...

//weaken security for local development
Size := SizeOf(DWORD);
if InternetQueryOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @flags, Size) then
begin
  flags := flags or SECURITY_SET_MASK;
  InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @flags, Size);
end;
```

SECURITY_SET_MASK is defined as:

```
SECURITY_SET_MASK = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION or 
SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA or
SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID or
SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID or
SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE;
```